SharpJS: Resizing image with large number of frames taking very long time to process even though frame size is low
I'm using SharpJS to resize a gif/webp image having large number of frames,
but I'm experiencing slow performance even though the frame size is 7kb, 15kb or 20kb and target frame dimension is 512x512. I have tried many gif and animated webp images to test it.
Here is relevant code snippet i have used:
    const resizeOption = {
      width: 512,
      height: 512,
      fit: 'contain',
      background: {r: 0, g: 0, b: 0, alpha: 0},
    }
    
    const config = {quality}
    if(delay){ config.delay = delay }
    
    return await sharp(buffer, {animated:true})
    .resize(resizeOption)
    .webp(config)
     // .timeout({ seconds: 1200 }) 
    .toBuffer();

How to hadle this problem ?
Version:
"sharp": "^0.33.4"

node --version
v20.9.0

